# How do I accept an answer?

Tags: support, faq, accepted-answer

I feel like such a jerk, because I haven't accepted anyone's answers to my questions, and I can't figure out how! Could someone please tell me how?

Comment: @MathMastersStudent: If you have an answer accepted, its checkmark should be *green*. You can unaccept an answer by clicking the checkmark again. Here, the checkmark should be grey at the moment, because you didn't accept the answer. Click it, it turns green (answer accepted). Click it again, it turns grey (answer not accepted). Do this as long as you wish here, but make sure that at some point you leave it at a green state.

Comment: Does accepting an answer bump the question up?

Comment: No, accepting an answer doesn't bump the question.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[Here's a detailed explanation.](https://math.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask)

In a nutshell, there's a grey checkmark on the left under the two vertical arrows and the vote count. Simply click the one of the answer you want to mark as the accepted answer:

[image: checkmark]

You can try here to see if it works :)

Comment: Also, I've noticed that you haven't voted on the answers. Please consider doing that as well.

Comment: OK. Is that what the grey up arrow is?

Comment: Exactly.${}{}{}$

Comment: And while we're at it, notice that you can (up)vote on commens also!

Comment: though thre is no rep on the line for upvoting g comments

Comment: Since this Q&A is in the FAQ, this answer may need to be updated. Specifically, the link now redirects to the tour (which does sort of mention accepting, but not in any detail). The screenshot is also old, but that's not a big deal since the interface is still the same there even if the buttons look different.

Answer (score 8):

[Here is more detailed information](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) on how to accept an answer and what the rules & suggestions regarding it are.