# I still haven't discovered how to vote on MSE or to favorite questions. Is this a bug in me or in my interface?

Tags: bug, bookmarks, up-votes

Sorry for such a noob question, but I have tried to find how to vote and so far have not succeeded. As I haven't been active here for very long O am happy not to rush into this, but as things go on it may begin to look like I am some kind of miserly curmudgeon, which troubles me.

At first I thought that the non-appearance of a "voting button" was due to the fact that I had not yet been awarded this "privilege", but now I am wondering if there is some technical problem.

I would really appreciate it if someone could have the patience and take the trouble to help me sort this out.

Thanks to all for all of these helpful answers. At last I can vote! Now just need to know how to accept an answer, so others are freed from my question!

Comment: What do you see to the left of your question? Do you see a number with arrows?

Comment: 15 rep allows you to vote up. 125 rep allows you to vote down. You have 844 rep so you should be able to do both.

Comment: @T.Bongers thank you. that comment is my "AHA" moment on this problem, i think. i naively assumed the arrows were merely decorative. that is one of the problems of aspergers types like myself. i am sure even without trying that you have diagnosed my problem correctly. thank you so much ;-)

Comment: And to favourite a question, press the star under the lower arrow. It will turn yellow :) The list of favourites can be located in your user profile.

Comment: The [tour](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour) wasn't helpful to you?

Answer (score 1):

From description of privilege to [vote up](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up)

> How do I vote up?
>   Click the large up arrow to the left of a post.

See also [How to Say Thanks in an Answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/how-to-say-thanks-in-an-answer/).

A picture taken from there illustrating how to upvote:

[image: How to upvote]

(It looks slightly different here, because the sites have slightly different design.)

---

For details about favorites, see:

- [How do favorite questions work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53585/how-do-favorite-questions-work)
- [What do "favorite tags" and "ignored tags" do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19173/what-do-favorite-tags-and-ignored-tags-do)

Again I will copy a picture from the above answer:

[image: Favorite]

---

For the question about accepting answers, which you have added later, see: [How do I accept an answer?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer)