# What does this mean 'Have you considered accepting an answer or starting a bounty for this question?'

Tags: support, bounty, accepted-answer, policy

Can anyone help me in informing how can I accept an answer? Also can anyone tell how can I start a bounty? I think I have no control about it but please help.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: For bounties see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/1052107)

Comment: ok i guess can understand that though it's strange sometimes i see those red comments from admin but usually not though i guess it could possibly be the fault of my computer viewing display

Comment: oh is it possible to accept more than one answer

Comment: nope you can't accept more than 1 answer. Did you see something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y33L1.png) . If so that is the system message so that you can attract an question and your question could be successfully completed

Comment: yea it is something like that pertaining to the same various questions i have asked weeks, months or years ago. One day or at one time in the past couple or 3 days i see those in red comments for all those pertinent back   questions and next minute I don't see those in 'red' remarks messages.

Comment: i can't accept more than one answer but it is true that if for example i am the one who posted the question then anyone else whoever can accept any answer to my question if they want?

Comment: Please visit the links and read them which I gave in my first comment. Those might answer most of your question. OP means the question asker. In his/her question only OP can accept a answer. That means if you asked a question only you can accept a answer.

Comment: ok for that but as far as putting bounty seems someone else can put a bounty on my question because it has happened to me at least twice and certainly wasn't myself who put the bounty as i knew nothing about be able to do that and likely would not have done so in any event

Comment: On this meta: [How do I accept an answer?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3286) (The first half seems as a duplicate of that question.) There are several links in the [accepted-answer tag-info](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/accepted-answer/info). And the same is true about [bounty](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/bounty/info).

Comment: Anyone (with sufficient reputation) can start a bounty on any question (after the question has been around for 2 days), and the person who starts a given bounty is the only one who can award that bounty. However, there is no connection between awarding a bounty and accepting an answer. Only the original poster (OP) of a question can accept an answer to that question.

Comment: One aspect common to bounties and acceptances is that each can apply to **only one** answer: a question can have at most one accepted answer, and a given bounty can be awarded to at most one answer (accepted or not). That said, multiple bounties can be offered and awarded on the same question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I accept an answer?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/how-do-i-accept-an-answer)

Comment: YEA i think now all my questions have been answered and further seems a meta acct associated  with chemistry and  physics i think also separate for each one. I don't see any official ans. block given here but only comments but that is ok.

Comment: yea i just said so but they are all in the comments which is fine with me. so ofcourse i can't choose accept an answer which in this case i would rather not have to do anyway since it is not any esp one but several comments though i can't seem to find that last complaint comment to which this pertains at the moment